# Equal strings are not equal on php

Tags: php

Hi guys hope you can help me,  I'm trying to compare two strings  but I get the same result always  "diferent" even when the string are equal.

here is the code:

```
$date = $row["day"];

var_dump($date);
var_dump($today);

if ($date != $today) {
    echo "<br>diferent";
} else {
    echo "<br>equals";
}
```

the `var_dump` for the two strings shows this:

`string(10) "03/30/2019"` this corresponds to `$date`

`string(309) "03/30/2019"` this corresponds to `$today`

As you can see both strings contain the same info but one has 10 chars and the other one 309 why is this happening?  is there a way to fix it and  prove they are equal?

I use JavaScript to set `$today`'s value so this might be the issue?

Comment: `var_dump(bin2hex($today));` and add it to your answer. Also look at the _source_, not the rendered output.

Comment: Please show how you get `$today`. Why do you use JavaScript for that at all?

Answer (score 0):

Dear Please see below code, need to convert both format code please follow below code

```
$date = $row["day"];
$date=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date));
$today=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($today));
var_dump($date);
var_dump($today);
if ($date != $today) {
echo "<br>diferent";
} else {
echo "<br>equals";
}
```

This will work properly.

Comment: I'm quite sure, if you put 309 characters in to strtotime then it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trim the two strings, that way any extra characters should be removed.

```
if (trim($date) != trim($today)) {
```

Or you can use strpos to see if $date is in $today.

```
if(strpos($today, $date) !== false){
    echo "<br>equals";
}else{
    echo "<br>diferent";
}
```